# File uploads using flask looking in CWD for file to upload instead of using users sample directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Basically my issue is, whenever I go to upload a file through Flask it wants the file that is being uploaded in the same directory as the Python file my flask server is being run from. This becomes an issue when I go to my local machine instead of my VM and it searches for /home/kali/Downloads/(sample name) instead of wherever the sample is on the windows machine ex(C:\temp(sample)). It also does this on the VM itself where it is only looking in the /home/kali/Downloads folder for the sample to be uploaded. It's almost like it skips the sample entirely.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, send_file
import os
import shutil
from flaskmalwarecheck import malwaresignature
from flaskmalwarecheck import formattedpdf
from flaskmalwarecheck import entropy
import argparse
from elastic import elasticupload

filetypes = [b'MZ']
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
 return render_template('attempt.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
 try:
    upload_folder = "/home/kali/Downloads/webserverup/"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        n = request.files['file']
        filename = n.filename
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            header = f.read(32)
        for call in filetypes:
            if call in header:
                n.save(os.path.join(upload_folder,filename))
                os.chdir(upload_folder)
                malware_file, ISO8601, hashmethod, arch, importeddlls, imphash, fuzzyhash,warnings = malwaresignature(n.filename)
                formattedpdf(n.filename,malware_file,ISO8601, hashmethod, arch, importeddlls, imphash, fuzzyhash,warnings)
                download()
                os.remove(n.filename)
                os.chdir('..')
                elasticupload()
                return redirect('/download', code=302)

         else:
            return redirect('/download', code=302)
 except FileNotFoundError as e:
    return redirect('/download', code=302)

@app.route('/download')
def download():
 return send_file('/home/kali/Downloads/webserverup/Sample.pdf', as_attachment=True)

@app.route('/transparent')
def transparent():
 with app.open_resource('flaskmalwarecheck.py', 'r') as e:
    contents = e.read()
    return contents


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("ip", help="Enter host IP", type=str)
parser.add_argument("port", help="Port to be hosted on", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host=args.ip, port=args.port, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

The code uploaded really wonky so if something is misplaced it most likely isnt in the actual code, but feel free to point it out anyways. If you also want to see the HTML page I can provide that, but I didn't think it was relevant. This is my first time working with Flask so any pointers would be greatly appreciated as well ;)

Comment: I would recommend against using `os.chdir` and instead just set the full file path in a variable, solely operating on that. Also why are you read-binary-opening the filename from the POST data  and then discarding the "header" (of the probably non-existent file) ( oh its meant to be indented). 
Also please use `secure_filename(n.filename)` from `werkzeug.utils` as your code has an arbitrary remote file replacement vulnerability.

Comment: @Zv_oDD Thank you for your input. I will get to work on this ASAP. I am still trying to determine if I want this to be public-facing or just a local webserver. However, either way it will be useful. The reason for the header analysis of the file is because the application behind the flask server can only take 'MZ' filetype so .dlls .exes but extensions lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the config variable `UPLOAD_FOLDER` to specify where the uploaded file goes & `secure_filename` to strip & sanitize the path

```
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route(...<route info>...)
def upload_file():
...
  filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
  file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
...
```

See Flask documentation on [Uploading Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)

Comment: Thank you for your input, I did make this change but the issue still persists. For example, when I go to upload a file from a different directory /home/kali/Filename.exe it still looks for the file in /home/kali/Downloads/Filename.exe . I checked this by adding the line print(os.path.abspath(filename). This ends up making the file not able to even be sent to the upload folder because it is looking for the file in the wrong spot. Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: the `file.filename` will be the original filename from the client side. as @Zv_oDD mentioned, you need to run `secure_filename` to strip & normalize the path info before saving it to the `UPLOAD_FOLDER`

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed the issue using your guidance along with a little bit of code tweaking.